# python setuptools entry point script can't find module

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point

I have the feeling I am missing some point here, and googling didn't get me far.

I am using `setuptools` for a command line script. All goes fine but after installation my own files are not "seen" by the automatically generated script of the entry-point. Imagine the following case:

file `a.py` contains:

```
a = 12
```

file `__main__.py` contains:

```
from a import a

def main():
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

file `__init__.py` is empty. File `setup.py` contains:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='tep',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.0.1',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'tep = tep.__main__:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

all are properly located in the directory structure:

- test_entry_point

  - tep

    - __init__.py
    - __main__.py
    - a.py
  - setup.py

Locally all works well. But after installation:

```
sudo -H python setup.py install
```

and invoking from a different shell either by using `tep` or by using `python -m tep`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'a'
```

So the file `a.py` is not visible in the scope after installation . Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you haven't specified an absolute path of the `a` module. Remember, `a` is in package `tep`. So you need to import like this in `__main__.py`:

```
from tep.a import a
```

Comment: Hi. unfortunately that doesn't work. It even stops the local invocation from functioning. e.g. `python tep/__main__.py` results in `ImportError: No module named 'tep'`. Keeping it as in the original post, the local invocation works, but the module is not found *after* installation.

Comment: @xaratustra Hm, cannot reproduce the problem, nor in local invocation neither after installing as a package. When you testing, are you always in `test_entry_point ` (i.e. directory containing `tep` subdir)? Are you using `virtualenv`?

Comment: @xaratustra also, I don't know if you are using `PYTHONPATH` and what your `sudoers` looks like, so check if these may somehow cause the problem, since you are using `sudo -H` to install your package. Try `sudo -H python -m tep` to see if that will change behavior.

Comment: well it seems you are right. It does work the way you predicted. It seemed that I had some problems with the shell. Thanks. Btw. I use no `virtualenv`. I am using `sudo` because I have a funny macports installation. But I use it for all of my packages and I have never problems.